# Jolt Spec for masking cards

Tags: json, regex, mask, jolt

How can I iterate through list and replace some elements in it?
I have this input

```json
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "clientId": "166734",
      "info": {
        "cards": [
          "378282246310005",
          "371449635398431"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I expect cards will looks like this  **`"cards" : [ "3782", "3714" ]`**

But in my spec do not work substring

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "info": {
            "cards": {
              "*": "=substring(@(1,&),0,@(1,4))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **shift** transformations to tame the cards array in order to prepare for **modify** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2].&",
          "info": {
            "cards": {
              "*": {
                "@": "&5[#5].&3.&2.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "info": {
            "cards": {
              "*": "=substring(@(1,&),0,4)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2].&",
          "info": {
            "cards": {
              "*": "&4[#4].&2.&1[#1]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If there can always only exist two components for ***cards*** then we make the whole spec shorter by using ***[first/last]Element*** functions, otherwise use **`"=(@(1,cards[0/1]))"`** by individually writing such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "info": {
            "c0": "=firstElement(@(1,cards))", //or "=(@(1,cards[0]))"
            "c1": "=lastElement(@(1,cards))",  //or "=(@(1,cards[1]))"
            "cards0": "=substring(@(1,c0),0,4)",
            "cards1": "=substring(@(1,c1),0,4)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2].&",
          "info": {
            "*s*": "&3[#3].&1.&(0,1)s"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note 1:**

You should not use `@(1,&)` for getting an array index.

**`@(1,&)` says:** Go up 1 level (`cards`) and get `0` and `1` **key** from the array with `&`. But You have an array and should get the **index** from it.

You can say get `&` in an array like this: **`@(1,[&])`**

**Note 2:**

For getting the first 4 elements in the string you don't need the `@(1,4)`. just say `4`

**Simpler solution:**

We can get the current level without going up 1 level with `@(0)` or `@0`: **`@0,0,4`**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "info": {
            "cards": {
              "*": "=substring(@0,0,4)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```